# What to put in the require block when developing a Laravel package?

Tags: laravel

I am learning how to develop a laravel package, and now I am about to upload it to packagist to use it via composer:

My current `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "Kadd3/laravel-package-test",
    "description": "laravel package test.",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "test test",
            "email": "test@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "require-dev": {
        "orchestra/testbench": "^3.8"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Kadd3\\Events\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/Helpers/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Kadd3\\Events\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Kadd3\\Events\\Providers\\EventsServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the `require` block is empty:

What should I put there? or should it be left empty?

Comment: Well, does your package require other libraries to function?

Comment: No, but I am using some laravel libraries.

Comment: You *could* define those libraries as requirements, in case Laravel core makes them optional at some point in the future.